# Redmine 3.1 Ruby Errors config options

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redmine

Is there a specific option that controls the stack trace for Ruby errors in Redmine's logfile? Whenever an error is thrown from a plugin i'm developing, it always reports that the error comes from the *sudo_mode.rb* file.

```
F, [2015-09-03T13:25:41.478307 #15053] FATAL -- : 
NoMethodError (undefined method 'map' for "[\"[\\\"\\\"]\"]":String):
  lib/redmine/sudo_mode.rb:63:in `sudo_mode'
```

When I had 3.0 installed, these errors always gave me the full stack trace so I could see exactly where things went wrong. How do I bring that functionality back?